How would I retrieve the PropertyBag of ListItems using the RenderListDataAsStream API?
Our customer has rather large lists and libraries in their SPO environment and we need to query a property bag entry from all list items of those large lists. Currently, we're successfully using the RenderListDataAsStream CSOM API and I would like to extend that logic but I can't figure out how to retrieve a ListItems's property bag (ListItem.Properties).
I know I can fall back to using the streamed ListItem ids to load the actual CSOM objects but that would be terribly slow since we're using the RenderListDataAsStream API specifically because the lists are so large in the first place.
I also played around with the RenderListDataParameters (especially the RenderListDataOptions and the ViewXml where I tried to include "Properties") as well as the RenderListDataOverrideParameters - to no avail. The property bag never shows up in the returned data.
Is there any direct way to achieve this?
